# How to get data from html form?

Tags: html

What is the most modern way to get data from an html form and email it to yourself?

Comment: The modern (PHP) way would be to use a ready-to-go PHP mailer class like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). Since the normal `mail()` function has many flaws.

Comment: thanks for the response! I will look into this now.

Comment: The server and/or PHP need to be set up properly for sending mail. But that's a lengthy topic and there are many ways to do it.

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to have a JQuery .sumbit() event handler on your submit button which would gather all the info from the form and send them to a backed controller which would actually send the email.

JQuery example:

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {

        // get the form data
        var formData = {
            'name' : $('input[name=name]').val(),
            'email' : $('input[name=email]').val(),
            'phone' : $('input[name=phone]').val()
        };

        // process the form
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : 'process.php',
            data : formData,
            dataType : 'json',
            encode: true
        })
            // using the done promise callback
            .done(function(data) {
                // log data to the console so we can see
                console.log(data);
            });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

The server side could look something like:

```php
<?php
// process.php

$errors = array(); 
$data = array();

    // Validation
    if (empty($_POST['name']))
        $errors['name'] = 'Name is required.';

    if (empty($_POST['email']))
        $errors['email'] = 'Email is required.';

    if (empty($_POST['phone']))
        $errors['phone'] = 'phone is required.';

    if ( ! empty($errors)) {
        $data['success'] = false;
        $data['errors']  = $errors;
    } else {

        // Send email here

        $data['success'] = true;
        $data['message'] = 'Success!'
    }
?>
```

In this way you would decouple client side logic (gather form data) and backend logic (send the email).

Comment: @Adam Subtruct , Are you ok with my answer? Is there anything you think is missing for this question to be flagged as answered?